# WPF application is crashing after publish

Tags: wpf, xaml, xamlparseexception

I've upgraded WPF application to Visual Studio 2k8. App is .NET 3.0 which is set as a platform in the project.

If I build project & release confiuguration, app is running well. 
If I try to publish it using ClickOnce, it is crashing because xaml resources couldn't be find.

Any idea?

Thank you very much.

P.S. It seem that XAML resources aren't really included in Resources in the assembly. If assemble is just rebuilded (without Publish) everything is ok and XAML are included in resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I solved this problem. 
My application has been upgraded from V2k5 to V2k8.

If .NET 3.0 is target platform, the problem exists. 
If .NET 3.5 is target platform, problem solved.

Thank you for your collaboration.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the One Click Deployment options on your project.
On the Publish tab, have a look at the Application Files section.

Some files might not have been included.

Comment: Thank you, but all files are included. 

Some WPF UserControls are not included in Resource section after Publish. It is not predictable when they are included after Publish.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong then, that should be the most important difference. Perhaps you could check the "Build action" on your files (select a file and check the Properties list).

Comment: It seems I solved this problem.

My application has been upgraded from V2k5 to V2k8. 

If .NET 3.0 is target platform, the problem exists. 
If .NET 3.5 is target platform, problem solved. 


Thank you for your collaboration.